# Heroku local web debug with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, heroku, intellij-idea, telegram

I'm writing a telegram bot in Java. This bot will be hosted on Heroku in future. For now I'm just building it with Gradle and run it locally with:

```
heroku local web
```

command. Is there any way to debug it using Intellij IDEA?

Comment: You can run your bot from IDEA without heroku and use getUpdates to receive messages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, running `heroku local` starts a normal Java process under the hood. You can confirm this by running `jps` (unsure if that works on Windows).

In order to debug with Intellij, you'll need to provide to proper JVM options to enable debugging. For example:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9090,server=y,suspend=n
```

You can put these in your `Procfile` or set them as `JAVA_OPTS` and reference that env var in your `Procfile`.

Once the `heroku local` process is started, you can confirm it's working by running:

```
jdb -attach localhost:9090
```

Then you can connect a remote debugger in Intellij on `localhost:9090`.

Comment: I tried this on a Heroku app I'm working on and it seems in my situation, adding those options to the Procfile didn't actually cause Heroku to send them to the process when it started it. However, adding it to the `JAVA_OPTS` worked fine; I just added this line to my `.env`:

```JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9090,server=y,suspend=n```